# php gd function to draw polyline from array

Tags: php, function, gd, polyline

may be you can help me. 
I need a function to draw polyline path from _GET or _POST string and save generated image to the folder. 
For example my link will looks like: http://img.domain.com/?points = 1,5,-70,300,250,500...
If image already generated and do not changed -> load it from folder. Else generate new one.

My code here:

```
if (isset($_POST['points'])) {

   $points = $_POST['points'];


   $image = imagecreate(200, 200);

   $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
   $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,   0, 0);

    ... polyline path drawing here...?
   imageline($image,  10,   10,  10, 190,   $black);

   header('Content-Type: image/png');
   imagepng($image);
   imagedestroy($image);

   ... how to save it to the server?

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To save the image you can use the second (optional) parameter of `imagepng`:

```
imagepng($image, 'saved.png');
```

For the polyline you will be calling `imageline` inside a loop -- exactly how depends on what your `$points` value is structured.

Answer (score 0):

To save an image to the server on the fly, use the image function's second parameter to specify a location and filename.

```
//specify the path on the server where you want to save the image
$path_image = 'saved-example.png';
imagepng($image, $path_image);

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Image will be saved to that path.